# Executar uma validação inserida em uma string

Tags: php, lógica

Tenho uma variável no PHP que monta uma string logica.

```
$str = "(('TR1'=='TR' OR 'TR2=='TR' OR 'TR'=='TR') AND ('10,0'=='10,1' OR '9,0'=='9,0'))";
```

gostaria de encontrar uma maneira que a validação fosse possivel, tipo:

if($str) "Um dos parâmetros de cada lado é válido";

Alguém já passou por isso, ou sabe uma forma de resolver?

Comment: Esses parâmetros TR1, TR, TR2, etc são strings, e no caso a primeira parte vai ser sempre true visto que 'TR' == 'TR' é true. Na segunda parte, após o AND, também será sempre true, pois '9,0' == '9,0'. Neste caso não faz muito sentido o porque do `IF`. Você pode explicar melhor?

Comment: Claro David, primeiramente muito obrigado pelo interesse em ajudar.. No exemplo sim a validação seria sempre verdadeira, mas o caso real é que a string será a montagem de uma leitura em banco de dados, onde a própria expressão é armazenada. Por isso preciso validar e somente proceder quando o resultado desta expressão for verdadeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para executar uma String como um comando no PHP, você pode usar a função "eval()".

```
<?php

eval('$var = (("TR1"=="TR" OR "TR2"=="TR" OR "TR"=="TR") AND ("10,0"=="10,1" OR "9,0"=="9,0"));');

echo $var;

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.eval.php

Comment: Ederson, muito obrigado, eu até tinha tentado utilizar a função eval(), mas não tinha tido sucesso. Muito agradecido pele mão.. desta forma deu certo...